# Intermittent 404 errors on IIS6, serving classic ASP content

Tags: iis-6, http-status-code-404, intermittent

We have 2 IIS6 web servers running in a cluster.

Intermittently we receive a 404 / 500 error, if it's a 500 error i get an email with the line number, i check that line in the asp file and it's always an include, check the log and it's reported as 404 not found.

I check the servers separately, and it's always one of the servers generating the error, not normally both.

The include file obviously exists.

So for some reason it randomly cannot find files that it has been serving every day for the past few years and I am pulling out my hair trying to figure out why.

Also, every time this happens i have to take the problem sever out of the cluster, do an iisreset and then put it back in the cluster again then it works fine.

Any ideas guys ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify the event viewer of the web server, to look something like this:

```
[ SystemTime]   2012-09-21T03:34:57.221Z
ResourceGroup   BRQSB1VALEAS667
Cluster resource 'FileServer-(  NameOfYourServer )(Cluster Disk 1)' in clustered service or application 'NameOfYourServer' failed.
```

I had the same problem you are experiencing. I could not find yet the reason why the fileServer is going down, but it is clear to me that error code 404 apppears after this event.

Comment: Unfortunately I was never able to find the problem and we stopped serving the website from this server after a month so was unable to check for this.